# repr equivalent in shell

Tags: bash, shell, python

In python i use:

```
repr('test')
```

for get the output:

```
"'test'"
```

I want to do the same but in the shell to be able to store this value in a variable. How can I do?

For example:
If I execute a command:

```
echo $test
```

I get the output:

```
ghjghj "' bhj ""'' bjhv "''hjuhd
```

In shell I want to do this:

```
test=repr(repr($test))
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what you mean. Do you just want to print a string? Save a string in a variable? Add double quotes around a string?

Comment: And what output do you expect from `test=repr(repr($test))`? Please forget python and show us what you need _in the shell_. You start with a variable `$test` whose value is `ghjghj "' bhj ""'' bjhv "''hjuhd`. OK, and what do you want from this?

Comment: if you mean `repr` as in "print all nonprintable chars as hex escapes" then `tput setaf 2 | perl -pe 's/([^[:print:]\n])/sprintf("\\x%02x", ord($1))/ge'` would print `\x1b[32m` ([source](https://superuser.com/a/895655/951886))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something similar to Python's `repr` is `printf %q` which could be combined with `printf -v` which "prints" into another variable instead of stdout. (though non-standard, it's supported in the printf built-in from bash and zsh):

`````
[prompt] foo=$(cat <<'EOT'
'"'<>\`'"'''()*@@@@$$$$````'''''
EOT
)
[prompt] printf '%q\n' "$foo"
\'\"\'\<\>\\\`\'\"\'\'\'\(\)\*@@@@\$\$\$\$\`\`\`\`\'\'\'\'\'
[prompt] printf -v bar %q "$foo"
`````

One practical use of this is when you want to pass commands through multiple ssh (e.g. when you cannot set forwarding on intermediate hosts with `ssh -J`), and even *one* level of escaping is too much to be able to keep track of (at least for me):

```
[prompt] cmd='echo "$USER'\''s \$HOME on $HOSTNAME is $HOME"'
[prompt] ssh localhost "$cmd"
luser12's $HOME on kgbvax is /home/luser12
[prompt] printf -v cmd %q "$cmd"
[prompt] ssh localhost ssh localhost "$cmd"
luser12's $HOME on kgbvax is /home/luser12

[prompt] printf -v cmd %q "$cmd"
[prompt] printf -v cmd %q "$cmd"
[prompt] printf -v cmd %q "$cmd"
[prompt] echo "$cmd"
echo\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\$USER\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'s\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\$HOME\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ on\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\$HOSTNAME\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ is\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\$HOME\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"

# OK, we're ready to go

[prompt] ssh localhost ssh localhost ssh localhost ssh localhost ssh localhost "$cmd"
luser12's $HOME on kgbvax is /home/luser12
```

**Beware however that `printf %q` will use the `$'...'` quote-escape format, which may not be supported by the remote shell** (though it's supported by bash, zsh, etc and supposedly slated to be included in a future version of the POSIX standard).

---

Bash and ksh93 also have `typeset -p` (also usable as `declare -p` in bash), but it only works with variables, not with literals:

```
[prompt] typeset -p foo
declare -- foo="'\"'<>\\\`'\"'''()*@@@@\$\$\$\$\`\`\`\`'''''"
[prompt]
```

As an alternative to `printf %q`, newer versions of bash also have the `${var@Q}` special expansion form:

`````
[bash] echo "${foo@Q}"
''\''"'\''<>\`'\''"'\'''\'''\''()*@@@@$$$$````'\'''\'''\'''\'''\'''
`````

Comment: Thank you very much. declare -p is newest

Comment: Very interesting. Declare and printf have effects bit different. printf return: foo\ \"\'\'bar\ \'\'\"\ foo\ \"\"\'\ bar

Comment: Declare return an more elegant and similar-python format: "foo \"''bar ''\" foo \"\"' bar"